# Show this double integral is equal to $2\,(||f||^2_2||g||^2_2-|\langle f,g\rangle|^2)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For integrable functions $f, g : I \to C$, define $\langle f, g \rangle = \int_{I}f(x)\overline{g(x)} \,\mathrm d x$ and $I\subset R$ is a bounded inerval with more than one element. How do we show that

$\int_{I}\int_{I}|f(x)g(y) − f(y)g(x)|^2 \,\mathrm d x \,\mathrm d y
=2\,(\|f\|^2_2\,\|g\|^2_2-|\langle f,g\rangle|^2)$

I think the appearance of both $x$ and $y$ is causing some confusion because we are not dealing with multivariable functions here, so I'm not sure what the double integral is actually doing. What I did was use the fact that for complex numbers $|z|^2=z\overline{z}$, we break up the left-hand side into four terms $\int_{I}\int_{I}|f(x)g(y) − f(y)g(x)|^2 \,\mathrm d x \,\mathrm d y=\int_{I}\int_{I}(|f(x)g(y)|^2+|f(y)g(x)|^2-f(y)g(x)\overline{f(x)g(y)}-f(x)g(y)\overline{f(y)g(x)})\,\mathrm d x \,\mathrm d y$

Now I am not sure how we integrate these terms.

Comment: The function $(x,y) ↦ f(x)\,g(y)$ is a multivariable function ;)

Comment: Use '\langle' and '\rangle' for delimiters, not '<' and '>'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to keep going.

\begin{align}
\int_{I}\int_{I}|f(x)g(y) − f(y)g(x)|^2 \,\mathrm d x \,\mathrm d y&=\int_{I}\int_{I}(|f(x)g(y)|^2+|f(y)g(x)|^2-f(y)g(x)\overline{f(x)g(y)}\\&\qquad-f(x)g(y)\overline{f(y)g(x)})\,\mathrm d x \,\mathrm d y\\[0.3cm]
&=\int_{I}\int_{I}(|f(x)|^2\,|g(y)|^2+|f(y)|^2\,|g(x)|^2-f(y)g(x)\overline{f(x)g(y)}\\&\qquad-f(x)g(y)\overline{f(y)g(x)})\,\mathrm d x \,\mathrm d y\\[0.3cm]
&=\int_I|g(y)^2\,\bigg(\int_I|f(x)|^2\,dx\bigg)\,dy
+\int_I|g(x)^2\,\bigg(\int_I|f(y)|^2\,dy\bigg)\,dx\\
&\qquad-2\int_I\int_If(y)\overline{g(y)}\,dy\,\overline{f(x)}\,g(x)\,dx\\[0.3cm]
&=\|f\|^2\,\int_I|g(y)|^2\,dy+\|f\|^2\,\int_I|g(x)|^2\,dx-2\langle f,g\rangle\,\int_I\overline{f(x)}g(x)\,dx\\[0.3cm]
&=\|f\|^2\|g\|^2+\|f\|^2\|g\|^2-2\langle f,g\rangle\,\overline{\langle f,g\rangle}\\[0.3cm]
&=2\|f\|^2\|g\|^2-2|\langle f,g\rangle|^2. 
\end{align}